# Plotting and saving R graph

Tags: r, bash

I have a bash script that tracks memory usage over time as a command is run. It spawns the desired command and then writes a log with column1 = "memory in use by program (gigs)" and column 2 is the time elapsed so far in seconds. e.g.

```
31.282 1470
31.565 1480
31.848 1490
31.989 1500
32.273 1510
32.414 1520
32.697 1530
32.980 1540
33.122 1550
33.405 1560
6.511 1570
6.935 1580
7.502 1590
7.926 1600
8.351 1610
8.775 1620
9.059 1630
9.483 1640
9.908 1650
10.333 1660
```

What I want to do is wait until the process is complete and then use R to plot a graph of memory usage over time and save it in the current directory. I was playing around with R and I know exactly what commands I need to use:

```
> heisenberg <- read.csv(file="4644.log",head=FALSE,sep=" ")
> plot(heisenberg$V2,heisenberg$V1,type="o",col="red",main="Memory Usage Over Time",xlab="Time (seconds)",ylab="Memory (gigabytes)")
> text(max(heisenberg$V2),max(heisenberg$V1),max(heisenberg$V1)) #Displays max value
```

But the part I am stuck on is saving the graph as a jpg or png. Or how I could execute this command within my bash script. Would I absolutely need to have another script written in R language and run it? Would this be possible to do all in one?

---

## Edit

Here is the code for my script.r

```
png("mem_usage_2965.png",height=800,width=800)
heisenberg <- read.csv(file="2965.log",head=FALSE,sep=" ")
plot(heisenberg$V2,heisenberg$V1,type="o",col="red",main="oases_k85",xlab="Time (seconds)",ylab="Memory (gigabytes)")
text(max(heisenberg),max(heisenberg),max(heisenberg))
dev.off()
```

Can anyone help as to why the text doesn't print the maximum value in the outputted png? I am calling it in a bash script like `R CMD BATCH script.r script.out`

Comment: Why aren't you computing the `max()` of `heisenberg$V1` and `heisenberg$V2`? at the moment you are computing a value that is the largest value in the `heisenberg` data frame for **both** coordinates (x and y) so no wonder it doesn't appear on the plot; it is outside the plot. I think you want: `with(heisenberg, text(max(V2), max(V1), max(V1)))` at least that is what is suggested by the original code snippet you showed. You do realise the new code doesn't match the original yes?

Comment: Upon looking more closely, yes I do realize the difference now. Thats because I simply opened the script.r that the bash script output, but I had forgotten to escape the $. Thus they were interpreted as null variables. I will try the with statement like you said. To be clear, what I want is to show the maximum value on the graph with a textual display.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your plot calls in:

```
jpeg("myplot.jpg")
....plot code here....
dev.off()
```

or

```
png("myplot.png")
....plot code here....
dev.off()
```

See their respective help pages: `?png` for details of other arguments.

For a PNG this would be:

```
png("my_plot.png", height = 800, width = 600)
plot(heisenberg$V2,heisenberg$V1,type="o",col="red",main="Memory Usage Over Time",xlab="Time (seconds)",ylab="Memory (gigabytes)")
text(max(heisenberg$V2),max(heisenberg$V1),max(heisenberg$V1)) #Displays max value
dev.off()
```

As for running this in a bash script, you need to invoke R to run your script containing the R code to load the data and draw the plots. For this there are several options, two are:

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore my_script.R
```

or use `Rscript`

```
Rscript my_script.R
```

where `my_script.R` is a text file containing syntactically-valid R code required to produce the plots.

Comment: So is there a way to do this within my bash script? Is it possible to use R in command-line?

Comment: See `?RScript` for details of a scripting interface to R. There are other ways, i.e. using `R CMD BATCH`. But this is another Question so you should ask another Question on that topic.

Comment: @LanceH Not within a bash script you can't, you need to invoke R to run R code. You could combine your snippet with RScript for example to invoke R and run the contents of the `.r` file.

Comment: `R CMD BATCH` seems like what I am looking for. I could output an r script via echoing within my bash script. I may then be able to do something like call the script somehow.

Comment: `Rscript` is probably better suited.

Comment: I am having trouble showing the maximum value on the plot. When I open the saved png there is no text.

Comment: @Dan can you post the image somewhere so we can take a look, and it would help if we had a reproducible example.

Comment: Odd, did you put both the `plot()` **and** the `text()` calls **inside** the `png()....dev.off()`. Edit your Q with **exactly** the code you are using. Also, we need a reproducible example, can you post the data somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking at the simple?
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html

you basically tell R to start saving a .png with:

```
png(file="blah.png")
```

then use:

```
dev.off()
```

to return to normal.